# Is there a command similar to Linux's command-not-found?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew

Most Linux operating systems have a package like `command-not-found` (http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/command-not-found), which provides suggestions when a shell command was not found, e.g. because the command was misspelt.

```
➜ puthon
No command 'puthon' found, did you mean:
 Command 'python' from package 'python-minimal' (main)
 Command 'python' from package 'python3' (main)
```

Is there similar functionality for OS X, e.g. through Homebrew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created [Homebrew-command-not-found](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found) just for that. It works exactly as you would expect, and supports 5000+ Homebrew formulae. it works with Bash, Zsh, and Fish.

It’s currently limited to correct spellings, e.g.:

```
$ ghc
The program 'ghc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
  brew install ghc
$ ghv
ghv: command not found
```

Install it with `brew tap homebrew/command-not-found`, then add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`/`~/.zshrc`:

```
HB_CNF_HANDLER="$(brew --repository)/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found/handler.sh"
if [ -f "$HB_CNF_HANDLER" ]; then
  source "$HB_CNF_HANDLER";
fi
```

We’d welcome a PR for misspelling support, though.

Answer (score 4):

Searching Google for "homebrew command-not-found" (without the quotes) one of the results was: [Ubuntu’s command-not-found equivalent for Homebrew on OSX](https://github.com/bfontaine/homebrew-command-not-found)

I have not personally tried using it, so I cannot comment on how well it may work.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `zsh`, which has a [`CORRECT` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html) that will suggest commands with a "nearby" spelling. Personally, I use `zsh` and [`prezto`](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto), which results in this:

[image: zsh and prezto auto correct]

It's nice because the command is red while typing if it's not a valid program name, which means I usually catch the typo before I even press enter. Valid command names are green, though, so I know when I've typed it right.

`zsh` can be installed via homebrew, and then adding something like `prezto` on top of that is easy (it's just a `git clone ...`, `ln -s ...`, and `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh`).